# Regex to match word with at least one space on either side

Tags: regex

Given these phrases:

```
Records
Records and Stuff
Stuff and Records
A Records Store
GoodRecords
RecordsFest
```

How can we use regex to match the word `Records` along with a space on either side? So I would want to match:

`[]` represents a space:

`Records[]` from Records and Stuff

`[]Records` from Stuff and Records

`[]Records[]` from A Records Store

No match for `Records, GoodRecords, RecordsFest`

So far, I have this regex: `\b[rR]ecords\b` which matches just the word `Records` without the spaces and it's quite not what I want.

Comment: Can you use a [conditional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html)? [`( )?\b[rR]ecords\b(?(1) ?| )`](https://regex101.com/r/aNNyeL/2)

Comment: @bobblebubble I looked at that, but it's less efficient than just writing out the two options

Comment: @Nick Indeed it's a bit less efficient! However worth to mention the coniditional too I think. Yours is a very nice solution. Any of those are fast enough I guess (few steps).

Comment: @bobblebubble I agree it's a cool solution :), and certainly would produce a more compact regex if the `Records` part got big.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex to match your desired result:

```
 +Records\b *| *\bRecords +
```

This matches **either**:

- `+` : one or more spaces
- `Records` : the word `Records`
- `\b` : a word boundary
- `*` : zero or more spaces; **or**
- `*` : zero or more spaces
- `\b` : a word boundary
- `Records` : the word `Records`
- `+` : one or more spaces

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/O5rS4h/1)

Note that we need the `\b` between `Records` and  `*` to ensure we don't match in the middle of a word.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late answer but you should try this:

```
/\bRecords\s|\sRecords\b/
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: This will not capture the space after `Records` in `A Records Store`

Answer (score 0):

This will match trailing or leading whitespace or both:

```
 \s(Records)\s|\s(Records)|(Records)\s
```

Note that [] is not the regex character for whitespace. Technically with [ ] you could match a whitespace, but with that you define a group only containing a whitespace. \s is the prefered character to use.

Comment: This will match `Records` in `GoodRecords Also` and `A RecordsFest`